# Working with datetime and arrays

Tags: python, arrays, datetime, numpy

A while ago, I have written some code to convert dates into epochs, i.e. seconds since a specific date. It works purely with standard operators (+,-,*,/ etc).

I start with numpy arrays (of ints) for year, month, day, hour, minute and second. I then convert to epoch like this:

```
>>> epoch = date2epoch(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)
```

It works pretty well, but I was interested to see how working with datetime compares in terms of performance. Without much surprise, datetime is faster when converting a single date. Example how I did this:

```
>>> t = datetime.datetime(2014,1,2)
>>> t_ref = datetime.datetime(2014,1,1)
>>> epoch = (t-t_ref).total_seconds()
```

which takes 0.5us per loop according to timeit, my function takes about 3.5us.

For arrays, I have not found a convenient or faster way so far.

As datetime.datetime only takes integer arguments, I can not convert my array of dates directly. If I do it in a loop for every element, this makes it much slower.
I tried working with numpys builtin type datetime64, but this requires strings of a certain format as input, including zero padding. Converting my arrays to this also takes long.

Hence, I am looking for either
- a fast way to generate an array of datetime objects from arrays as given
- a fast way to convert my arrays of dates to a format useful for another function

I have checked other questions but, so far, found nothing that relates to this situation.

Does anyone have an idea how to do it?

### Update

Trying to provide more examples below.
Again, year,month, etc. are numpy arrays of type int and shape (365,).
(previously, I had used float when computing my own function. With int, the results are now even slightly better)

```
>>> my_epoch = date2epoch(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)

>>> date = np.column_stack((year,month,day,hour,minute,second))
>>> dt_ref = datetime.datetime(2014,11,1)
>>> dt_epoch = np.array([(datetime.datetime(y,m,d,h,mi,s)-dt_ref).total_seconds()
                         for y,m,d,h,mi,s in date])

>>> np.all(dt_epoch == my_epoch)
True

>>> dt_epoch_2 = np.zeros(365)
>>> for i in range(365):
        dt_epoch_2[i] = (datetime.datetime(*date[i]) - dt_ref).total_seconds()

>>> np.all(dt_epoch_2 == my_epoch)
True
```

Timeit results:
my_epoch: 90us per loop
dt_epoch: 530us per loop
dt_epoch_2: 550us per loop

Comment: So, the for every element loop calling datetime.datetime is slower than your function?

Comment: yes, if I wrap those three lines into  "for i in range(365):" it takes 180us per loop. my function with arrays of length 356 takes 110us per loop. Edit: sorry, 110us not 1.1us per loop...

Comment: Have you tried using a single line approach to create your vector?  I started with `ref_dt = datetime.datetime(2014,1,1)` and `beg_dt = datetime.datetime(2016,1,1)`, then the TIMEIT result was:  `%timeit("epoch = [((beg_dt+datetime.timedelta(days=i))-ref_dt).total_seconds() for i in range(366)]") #100000000 loops, best of 3: 6.81 ns per loop`  I think this will be faster, but I don't have your homebrew function to test against.  Do you have your loop to share as that may be the issue as well?

Comment: two replies to dblclik: 
a) That is actually one of those examples I was refering to as being "not related to the situation" in other questions. You are using a generator method for equidistant time steps, I have arrays that could be composed of random dates. 
b) I tried your code and get around 6.35ns per loop, similar to you. I tried my code for an array of the year 2016 and get around 6.35ns per loop. I tried my code for a single date and get 6.35ns per loop. This seems wrong, but I don't know what happened.

Comment: I have just retried your code in a timeit.timeit() function with setup code etc., like I did in my question. Here, your code takes 2.7seconds for number=10000, my Code takes 1.1seconds. Still no idea where the difference to the %timeit method comes from...

Comment: @JohannesHinrichs:  Strange the difference in %timeit and .timeit()...  If you have a random array you could just iterate over in one line, but it sounds like you're doing that.  Are you using these functions in a production code that's bigger, or just messing around in Python with this?

Comment: @dblclik: I just played around with %timeit. It seems to me that it does not operate on code supplied as a string, hence we were just timing how long it takes to define a string :) Regarding your question: I use the functions in other code for my research. It is nothing computation time critical, I'm just trying to better understand how things in python work and how to program properly.

Comment: @JohannesHinrichs: Good to know that iPython's magic function expects different syntax than Python's builtin timeit().  Always a good thing to try and understand the code at it's core, hat's off to you!